# Getting "TypeError: method takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" with "self" as argument

Tags: python-3.x, methods, typeerror

I am trying to store each line of a txt file in a list. Getting the error mentioned in the title even though my methods contain self as an argument. Here's my codes:

This is corpus.py

```
class Corpus():

def __init__(self, corpus_name):
    self.corpus_name = corpus_name

def corpus_to_list(self):
    corpus = open(self.corpus_name, "r")
    my_corpus = corpus.split("\n")
    corpus.close()
    
    return my_corpus
```

and this is main.py

```
import corpus as corp

def main():
    corpus = corp.Corpus("review.txt")
    corpus_list = corpus.corpus_to_list()
    print(corpus_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Make sure the file with the class definition is saved properly, and you're referencing the correct file.

Comment: corpus.py seems saved properly but I couldn't understand what do you mean with your second sentence. I'm a newbie in python so can you elaborate please?

Comment: I mean make sure that you don't accidentally have a copy of the file without a `self` parameter. Your code looks fine, so the simple explanation is this isn't the code being run. Also, try restarting your IDE if you're using one.

Comment: Oh I see, there is no copy of the file. I was using jupyter lab and when I restarted it started working again. Don't know why I didn't think about it before. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Np. When in doubt, restart everything to make sure old code wasn't cached somewhere and being run instead.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind.